# multiple conditions in same column with relation

Tags: sql, ruby

Here is the case:

There is a user table

```
id     email      orders_counter
=================================
1      a@a.com    5
2      b@b.com    3
3      c@c.com    0
```

And a user data table for user's other data

```
id     user_id      title      value
=======================================
1      1            Name       Peter Johnson
2      1            Tel        31546988
3      2            Name       Alan Johnson
4      2            Tel        56984887
```

If I want to fetch all user that

```
1, orders_counter greater then 3
2, Name contain 'Johnson'
3, Tel contain '88'
```

AT THE SAME TIME

What is my sql, and if I want to do it rubyonrails way
what is the ActiveRecord code
I know I can it one by one and then join all of them together, but it waste too much resource while conditions build up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select * From `user` u
inner join `userdata` d on d.user_id=u.id and d.title='Name' and d.value like '%Johnson%'
inner join `userdata` c on c.user_id=u.id and c.title='Tel' and c.value like '%88%'
where orders_counter > 3
```

the way that you've got your user data table structured, you'll almost always have to join on that table several times in order to "pivot" those values into columns.  I'd recommend just creating a table that has name and tel as columns.  then the query becomes a lot more simple

```
select * from `user` u
inner join `user_data` d on d.Tel like '%88%' and d.Name like '%johnson%'
where u.orders_counter > 3
```

Comment: yes I know, it in fact not store name or tel, it store something like interest, hobby, father name, mother name, work address. and it will expand as many as the client's need from time to time

Answer (score 0):

try this one up,

```
SELECT   a.*, b.*
FROM     user a
            INNER JOIN data b
                ON a.id = b.user_ID
WHERE   a.orders_counter > 3 AND
        (b.title = 'NAME' AND b.value like '%johnson%') AND
        (b.title = 'TEL' AND b.tel like '%88%')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select *
from  user U  join user_data D
on    U.id=D.user_id
where U.orders_counter>3
and   D.title='Name' and value like '%Johnson%'
and   D.title='Tel' and value like '%88%'
```